# 20:04 upgrade has broken Printing/Scanning

Tags: printing, 20.04, scanner

I'm having issues with my Deskjet 2634 since updating to 20:04.
Nothing prints or Scans
Cable connected.
If I delete all printers and re-insert USB cable it's immediately found but if I ctrl + P on a document then "No destination" can be seen to the right.
I also can't scan.
I tested the printer/scanner & cable on my laptop which is running 18:10 and it works ok.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. No response has been able to help thus-far. Irriting - especially as everything was fine with Ubuntu 18.04.  Surely a simple problem?